# how to feed data to each option in choice field django

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to create an api to feed opening time and closing time of restaraunt for each day in a week.All days are in choice field.How can i do that

models.py

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    restaraunt=models.ForeignKey(Restaraunt, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='restaraunt_name')
    days=models.CharField(choices=DAYS,max_length=255)
    opening_time=models.TimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=False)
    closing_time=models.TimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.restaraunt)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have different open hours for each day you should create a separate Days Class with the appropriate values. If you need to serialize the Schedule class a simple ModelSerializer should do the job